# Install firefox driver on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, firefox, python3

I have installed firefox driver on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and it's installed under

```
$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

I am using the following simple python script to test selenium

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
#binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
print(browser.page_source)
browser.close()
display.stop()
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
File "tests.py", line 16, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Complete version information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

This is a 100% OS issue because on other OSes like Windows and macOS I have tested, and the code works. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Which reading the suggested duplicate thread provided one of the solution was to look into `geckodriver.log`. My `geckodriver.log` stated

```
1524778083599   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1524778083603   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:58448
1524778084607   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.xBi1jOarZ06h"
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
```

In command line I exported the display like

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
```

After export, geckodriver.log is stating

```
 1524778146749  geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
 1524778146753  geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:55524
 1524778147756  mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.nWOzb0ngG3gm"
```

But now I am getting following error on the command line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tests.py", line 16, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to start browser /usr/bin/firefox: other os error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate on Stack Overflow: [Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46809135/4518341). There are some other questions about the same issue on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @wjandrea already read and posted the feedback in the question

Comment: OK, looks like you're making progress. Please keep researching the issue. I've found more questions related to the error you're currently getting. If it wasn't clear, we expect you to thoroughly research an issue before asking a question. See [ask]

Comment: Under which display server are you running Firefox and Selenium? One of the error messages is “Failed to connect to Mir”.